# Open the second tab in the view as default tab

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a link to an action here:

```
<a ng-if="dashBoardInformation.isVisible" 
ng-href="@Url.Action("SomeController", "Home")?id= {{siteSelection.siteCode}}#tab2"> Payment
</a>
```

And it fails to go to the `tab2` tab after I click on it. It goes to `tab1` instead. All the tabs are shown below:

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-disabled="isLoading">    
<!--Tab Menu Start -->    
<tabset>        
    <tab heading="Accounts" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"> </tab>        
    <tab heading="Payment" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"> </tab>        
</tabset>    
</div>
```

Can anyone show me how to present the second tab as default tab? I think the `Url.Action` has some problem.

My ideas so far are:

1. after clicking the link, remove `active` class from `tab1`, and add
   `active` class to `tab2`.

   2. Add another parameter of `string TabID` to
      the action method.

Comment: What are you using for the tabs functionality? Looks like Bootstrap, based on the `data-toggle="tab"` attribute.

Comment: Yes it is Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilize the Bootstrap API to select the tab. It doesn't happen automatically. The code for that is basically:

```
$tab.tab('show');
```

Where `$tab` is the actual tab element, not the content that's displayed when you click it. To get at that, I'd suggest something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (location.hash !== '') {
        $('[data-toggle=tab][href=' + location.hash + ']').tab('show');
    }
});
```